# MySQL HA Solutions

Tags: mysql, high-availability, mysql-replication, percona-xtradb-cluster, tungsten

I am evaluating the options to build MySQL HA and found the below solutions

1. Percona XtraDB Cluster,
2. Tungsten Replicator, and
3. MySQL Cluster.

Could you please help me to choose the best one with their pros and cons?

The Percona XtraDB Cluster, Does it change the InnoDB storage engine to XtraDB? Can I rollback to the MySQL native replication from Percona XtraDB Cluster?

Edited my Question.

Comment: You haven't said what would be "pros" or "cons" for you

Comment: You haven't even said what kind of application this is for. Note that MySQL Cluster is generally unsuitable for web applications.

Comment: Another choice: https://github.com/jayjanssen/Percona-Pacemaker-Resource-Agents/blob/master/doc/PRM-setup-guide.rst

Comment: it is web application developed on Magento E-commerce platform and PHP.

Comment: Edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no ultimate solution, a proper solution depends on your needs. MySQL Cluster uses memory-only storage and fully synchronous protocol based on 2-phase commit. So, if you have a ot of data you will need plenty of RAM to use the MySQL cluster. Percona XtraDB Cluster uses synchronous replication too but from my own experience its replicator is not stable enough, I have had some odd problems with it. But if you don't expect high write load (say, you write only several records per sec) on your DB I'd recommend it. Tugsten Replicator seems to be asynchronous only. So, if you need synchronous replication go with MySQL Cluster or Percona XtraDB Cluster, if you can live without it, try Tungsten.

Comment: The Percona XtraDB Cluster, Does it change the InnoDB storage engine to XtraDB? Can I rollback to the MySQL native replication from Percona XtraDB Cluster?

Comment: Yes, XtraDB and InnoDB are fully compatible

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is - but the effort involved, and the information you would need to supply goes way beyond what's possible to provide in a question / answer here.

Since your question is so wide of the mark, I would recommend you go seek profesional advice on what the best approach is - and plan on getting on-going support for the products.

Comment: If you have any experience or knowledge please share.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to say what is the best solution for you and your application without knowing more details about your system setup, but as a fourth suggestion I can give to DRBD (Drbd is a block device which is designed to build high availability clusters.) if you are running some kind of Linux OS..?